# flutter : how to flip this path clip Bezier

Tags: flutter, bezier, clip-path, flutter-clippath

I have this shape
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuhjd.png)

I want to flip it to be like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeUju.png)

this is the original code

```
class CustomMenuClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.white;

    final width = size.width;
    final height = size.height;

    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, 8, 10, 16);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(width - 1, height / 2 - 20, width, height / 2);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(width + 1, height / 2 + 20, 10, height - 16);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, height - 8, 0, height);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

this is the [github repository](https://github.com/TechieBlossom/sidebar_animation_flutter)
I don't mind if it comes to a half-circle.

Comment: Welcome to SO but please: remember to at the very least look at your post after submiting. Your images are not images right, because you forgot [the exclamation point that turns them into images](/markdown).

Answer (score 0):

I think is should be something like this:

```dart
     Path getClip(Size size) {
        Paint paint = Paint();
        paint.color = Colors.white;
    
        final width = size.width;
        final height = size.height;
    
        Path path = Path();
        path.moveTo(width, 0);
        path.quadraticBezierTo(16, 10, 8, 0);
        path.quadraticBezierTo(height / 2,  width, height / 2 - 20 ,width - 1);
        path.quadraticBezierTo( height - 16, 10, height / 2 + 20, height - 16width + 1);
        path.quadraticBezierTo(height, 0, height - 8, 0);
        path.close();
        return path;
      }
```

I would not recommend this, since different devices might reproduce different behaviors. Maybe using `size.width` and `size.height` might be a better idea for responsiveness.

Comment: @Sam I will test it and change it to see what is wrong with it, will update the answer.